# City Attractions - How to express this in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario

In English, City Attractions would donate interesting things to see in a city (such as museums, restaurants, city parks etc).

How would you express this in Spanish?

I think it would be:
*Visita turística: Atracciones en la ciudad* (Literally: Sightseeing: Attractions in the city)

However, I am not sure if "[Atracciones](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/attraction)" carries the same meaning. It is defined as such in [SpanishD!ct](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/attraction), but I cannot find *"Atracciones en la ciudad"* occurring very often when searching Google.

Comment: I usually see it as "reclamos turísticos."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're missing a part that usually goes with attraction: **tourist**.

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourist_attraction):

> A **tourist attraction** is a place of interest where tourists visit,
> typically for its inherent or an exhibited natural or cultural value,
> historical significance, natural or built beauty, offering leisure and
> amusement.

As you can see in the Spanish [version](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atracci%C3%B3n_tur%C3%ADstica) of the page, in Spanish we use the same pair: **atracción turística**. You can also use: **punto de interés** (turístico).

I think that "atracciones turísticas" is more used than "atracciones de la ciudad". If you are in a specific city, it's a bit redundant to include "de la ciudad". If you want to look for those special places in Google, just search: "[NAME OF THE CITY] atracciones turísticas".

In Spain, [atracciones](https://dle.rae.es/atracci%C3%B3n) (plural) alone is mainly used for

> 5. f. Cada una de las instalaciones recreativas, como los carruseles, casetas de tiro al blanco, toboganes, etc., que se montan en la feria
>    de una población y que, reunidas en un lugar estable, constituyen un
>    **parque de atracciones**. U. m. en pl.

Being
ES parque de atracciones
EN [theme park](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/theme-park)

> a large permanent area for public entertainment, with entertaining
> activities and **big machines** to ride on or play games on, restaurants,
> etc., sometimes all connected with a single subject

Those big machines are called **atracciones**.

Comment: In my heading, I did want to convey the sense of "the city". If I did `visita turística: atracción turística de la ciudad` would that work or would it sound too odd? I guess I could shorten it to `atracción turística de la ciudad`. I'd love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: @big_smile Yes, it sound odd because it's a bit redundant if you use "turística" twice. You can translate "City Sightseeing: Tourist Attractions" as "Itinerario por la ciudad: Monumentos y Puntos de Interés", for example.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe "puntos de interés" or "puntos de interés turístico".

Answer (score 3):

I just checked with a Peruvian friend  who works in the tourism sector there, she said:

*“Destino turístico”* means a place or city, like Cusco or Machu Picchu

*“Atracciones turísticas de la ciudad”* means the different “sites or attractions” that a tourist would want to visit in a given city, for example, like in Lima you would want to go to [Malecón de Miraflores](https://www.tripadvisor.co/Attraction_Review-g294316-d2555977-Reviews-Miraflores_Boardwalk-Lima_Lima_Region.html).

She also cautioned, *“un parque de atracciones/diversiones”* means amusement parks, which are death traps in some Latin American countries! ☹

Comment: Good answer. +1